# How to use with api Custom Object Detection in IBM Cloud Watson Visual Recognition? Is threshold not set properly?

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, object-detection, object-detection-api, visual-recognition

In Visual Recognition in IBM Cloud, I created a custom model for object detection and created a classifier to detect a specific object.
I ran the test (analysis of the image) in the GUI as shown in the image below, and it worked.

[test result in the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9SAV.png)

However, when I hit the api in curl and ran it, it did not return any of the values it detected, despite analyzing the exact same test image as the above image.
I ran it as follows. (I executed two patterns.)

[pattern 1]

```curl
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{my_api}" -F "features=objects" -F "collection_ids={my_ids}" -F "images_file=@{my_image}" -F “threshold=0.2” "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v4/analyze?version=2019-02-11"
```

[pattern 2]

```curl
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{my_api}" -F "features=objects" -F "collection_ids={my_ids}" -F "images_file=@{my_image}" -F “threshold=0.2” "{my_url}/api/v4/analyze?version=2019-02-11"
```

[test result with api]

```curl
{
"images": [
    {
        "source": {
            "type": "file",
            "filename": "IMG_2845.png"
        },
        "dimensions": {
            "height": 1792,
            "width": 828
        },
        "objects": {}
    }
]
```

}

For some reason, the contents of objects come back empty.

Am I missing some way to write it or a step to follow?
I don't see how to specify threshold in the article I'm referring to or the official reference, so maybe I'm not specifying it properly.
(If threshold is not specified, it defaults to 0.5. I'm thinking of lowering threshold to 0.2 , because the custom classifier I created this time didn't show detection accuracy above 0.5).

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve this problem.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0):

When you got a result in the GUI, what was the score?
The lowest score threshold you can provide in the v4 API is 0.15, perhaps try that instead of 0.2 (from the curl commands above)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As you can see in the image above(test result in the GUI), the scores are 0.3 for left_oya and 0.23 for left_ko. I tried again with thresholds of 0.15 in the v4 API, but the contents of objects were blank as well.

Comment: IMHO, this is threshold related. The quotes that you have around the threshold parameter don't look right. I think you have copied and pasted them from somewhere, so replace the `”` with `"` .